# How to test the interaction with the database PHPUnit?

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, phpunit

To test the PHP code I am using PHPUnit. 
Presently engaged in writing of the application architecture, while using the template Data Mapper. Accordingly, most of the tests should be reduced to the verification code interaction with the database. CRUD operations with an entity, etc. I think there should be checked directly on the database, and not replaced by a stub objects. Is testing the interaction with the database module? And how to conduct this test. Whether to use DBUnit. how? I ask not that you can read in the documentation, and specifically about the best solutions that come with experience. Thank you!

```
protected function update($obj) {
        $values = array(":id"    => $obj->getId(),
                        ":title" => $obj->getTitle(),
                        ":path"  => $obj->getPath(), 
                        ":type"  => $obj->getType(),
                        ":size"  => $obj->getSize());
        $this->updateStmt->execute($values);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to test. Usually a test against a database should be avoided, but sometimes it can't.

Comment: I added example of method into my question above.
Do I need to test these methods, and how?

Comment: You would test that the individual methods `getPath(), getType(),` etc... work using the Mock subsystem to control what they return, to ensure that your code works when certain values are returned.

To actually test using the database, take a look at the PHPUnit plugin called DBUnit. This will allow you to interact with the database to ensure your CRUD methods work properly.

Comment: Testing the interaction with the database - it is unit testing? Or it is integration testing?